# How can I manage websites settings in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, electron, chromium

I'm creating a browser using *Electron*. And it opens websites using `webview`.

```
<webview id="View" useragent="..." src="https://example.com/" plugins="" preload="file/dir/webview.js" webpreferences="..." enableremotemodule="false" allowpopups=""></webview>
```

Now I've got a question, how can I detect when a website is trying to request access to something using **JS**/**Node**?
**The explanation of my question:**

[image]

Every website in chrome has its own settings, and they can be access by clicking **Site settings** in the page info window (look up in the picture) or by going to *chrome://settings/content/siteDetails*.

[image]
And the *website settings* include whether it can or can't access the user location, use the microphone, use JavaScript, Senf Notifications, etc.
**How can I control those settings of websites in electron?**
[image]

And **how can I detect when a website is trying to gain access to one of those permissions?** (just like how *Wexond* does, Wexond is a browser that is built using *Electron*)